# giant glass impact

Tags: effects, sound-design

I'm attempting to create a giant glass impact - a big hit on a thick glass tunnel, that doesn't break or crack from the force. The glass is part of a tunnel, similar to what you find in an aquarium. I've tried all sorts, and can't quite get the weight of the sound to feel right - any tips/ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would record at 192K hitting softly a large empty vase with a rubber mallet and play that back at 48K and possibly pitch it down further.

Also try adding in detailed debris after the hit so you get that "shaking feel". Also try some deep metal stresses like you hear in a submarine when it hits something - that might help. I don't know...

I would go so far as to ask the video editor to add in a shaking effect on the visual as it hits so you see a shake - that's worked wonders for other movies and sounds to make it "feel bigger".

There are no cracks in the glass at all? Is it just going to be a solid thump? In that case, I would just find a lower-mid to mid frequency transient that sounds like glass (rolled off so it sounds like it's coming from outside) and adding in a lower thump - like a bass drum hit or explosion - cleverly edited and blended together so you get a big impact...

Hard to give advice on this one - hope what I wrote helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys! Unfortunately I don't have access to a contact mic on this project, so am solely reliant on the FX library - so I'll give some of Ryans tips a go this morning. There are no cracks in the glass; just a big impact at speed! Very hard brief.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes the biggest sounds come from smaller sources.  Try to find a regular sized glass tube that resonates a little, and then run some contact mics.  slow it down and see what you come up with.

You can also experiment with metal tubing and contact mics for different layers.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have used contact mics on Acrylic tubes and Plexiglass. you might also want to visit a junk yard and grab an old Windshield if you brace it right and support it you hit then pretty hard without them breaking or cracking.

Answer (score 0):

As above, I 'd suggest finding a thin-walled glass vase. What you do is then strike it so that  it rings. This sound can then be pitch down and combined with recorded impacts from acrylic and and metal tubes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried playing with tuning forks?  I've had great success for big resonating sounds by processing the tones.  Along with a solid impact it might work for your situation